# When is the item I get from a box decided?

Tags: mario-kart-8

I've noticed that the worse your rank the better the item (it's fair I guess). However if I hit a **<kbd>?</kbd>** box when I'm 10th and by the time the roll is done I'm 4th, will the item still be randomized as if I was 10th or will it take into account my new position ?

In other word :  does passing other players lower the power of an item that is still randomizing (rolling), or is the roll already decided when I hit the **<kbd>?</kbd>** box ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's decided when you hit the box.

Therefore, you can hit the item button to get the item earlier without affecting what you will get.  The only reason I can think of not to press the item button is if you're afraid to overdo it and spam the item by accident.

Unfortunately, I could not find a source for this.  The most efficient way for you to test it by yourself (by passing large groups of players) is to use a lightning before a set of itemboxes when being close to group of racers. You could also use a star before a set of itemboxes, then take a shortcut.

Comment: So is there any reason not to press the item button in order to get your item earlier?

Comment: No, the only reason I can think of is if you're afraid to overdo it and spam the item by accident.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't find one, but the most efficient way for you to test it by yourself (by passing large groups of players) is to use a lightning before a set of itemboxes when being close to group of racers. You could also use a star before a set of itemsboxes, then take a shortcut.

Comment: Not exactly a source, but it's been like this for every Mario Kart game with online abilities (i.e. starting with MKDS), simply because it lets your system tell all the other racers what item you're about to get much faster. Double Dash!! and earlier instead determined your item upon the roulette finishing.